# How I disable cache to JS and CSS?

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

Can I disable cache on pages inside Azure AD B2C?

Sometimes I have to force reload and disable cache via Inspect (on Edge) because my scripts don't update.

Comment: We recommend you to `clear your browser cache`. If you are using custom UI  you can add the data-preload="true" attribute in your HTML tags to control the load order for CSS and JavaScript. Please check the  [guidelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/custom-policy-ui-customization#guidelines-for-using-custom-page-content) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

(Moving from comments to answer)

We recommend you to `clear your browser cache`. If you are using custom UI you can add the `data-preload="true"` attribute in your HTML tags to control the load order for CSS and JavaScript. Please check the [guidelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/custom-policy-ui-customization#guidelines-for-using-custom-page-content) for more information.